# PHP \n escape character

Tags: php, string, escaping

How come php process doesn't recongize the \n escape character in the string of this statement:

echo " testing \n testing2";

why?

Comment: html -> br tag || text file -> newline character.........

Comment: This is a valid question people...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

End of Line character means nothing in HTML, which is supposed to be PHP output.

The next line in HTML is `<br/>` tag, So you should output that :

```
echo "<br/>";
```

You can also change all occurrences of `\n` in a string to `<br/>` via `nl2br` function as noted by my friend.

Answer (score 5):

I'm gonna go out on a limb here and guess that you wrote a page like this:

```
<?php

echo " testing \n testing2";

?>
```

And that the HTML output looks like:

```
testing testing2
```

Which is because HTML condenses white-space. You'll need to use some HTML elements to make the output *look* the way you think it should:

```
echo " testing <br /> testing2";
```

Answer (score 3):

When used in a HTML context, `\n` linebreaks will not be visible except in the HTML sourcecode as HTML uses `<br />` for linebreaks. To convert them, use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br).

You also need to be careful how your string is quoted. Escape sequences like `\n` are only parsed in double-quoted `"strings"`. In single-quoted `'strings'` they are not parsed.

Answer (score 2):

It does, take a look in the source code. If you want to see it in the browser, use

```
echo nl2br(" testing \n testing2");
```

Browser ignores ignores excess whitespace (including a newline) and converts it to a space. You need HTML tags (e.g. `<br />`) to manually break lines.

Comment: But for the `nl2br()` function call!

Answer (score 1):

If you go to "View Source" in your browser, then you'll see that it has inserted a line break. However, in HTML, a line break is interpreted as whitespace and doesn't start a new line. As @Czechnology says, you want to use `nl2br` to replace the newlines with HTML line breaks (`<br>`).

Please also remember to accept the best answer when you ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

Because your navigator think you want to display html
whereas you want to display plain text. Just add a
header explaining what type of content you want to display :

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo " testing \n testing2";
```

Comment: This gives output in newline,But at the same time it displays html code

Answer (score -1):

```
$teststring = ;
echo nl2br($teststring);
```

and type everything you want in `$teststring`